# Programmatically set selected index of a ComboBox in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I want to, while avoiding databinding, to set the selected index in a ComboBox in a DataGridView. It is not connected to a DB.

All solutions I have found have the DataGridView connected to a Database, which I have not, so I couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: In a DataGridViewComboBox, programmatically select an index.

Comment: You need to cast the cell to a datagridviewcomboboxcell....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn has no SelectedIndex or SelectedValue properties, you can try and set the value like this example:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmbCurrencies = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)myDataGridView.Columns["ComboboxCurrencyColumn"];

var currencies = entities.currencies.Select(c => c.currencyName).DefaultIfEmpty().ToList();     

cmbCurrencies.DataSource = currencies;
```

and then:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= myDataGridView.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
         myDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["Index of Combobox Column"].Value = "Pound";
    }
```

See also if [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/57df7b19-4929-47e3-9793-9a6fba278595/set-selected-index-of-combobox-column-in-datagridview?forum=winformsdesigner) may help.