# Adding ComboBox to Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox, rowdatabound

I found a way to add a combobox to DataGridview (Winform) cell, but I have not found an event like ItemDataBound of DataGridView to set a value to comboBox. And do not know how to set a selected value of a comboBox to DataItem property of a current row (of a DataGridView) :(

Please give me some clues to do this task

Thanks you so much

Comment: have you tried anything for it ?

Comment: do you want to add combo box in datagridview

Comment: @DhavalPatel yes, I did but no luck

Comment: @Sathish Yes, I meant it. I want to have a comboBox in every row of DataGridView. I want to set comboBox value when item data bound event (not found this built-in event or a similar one, please help), and every time when user select an item of a comboBox, the selected item will be assigned to a data item property

Comment: set which value to combo box?

Comment: @Sathish for example: comboBox contains 2 values (Males(value 1), Female(value 2)...if the person X is male, the comboBox will select Male. If user selects Female in comboBox, the value 2 must be apply for that person

Comment: if you select the value it assign in that cell right?

Comment: @Sathish yes, and when list data, every combox box must select an appropriate value of that cell as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57732/discussion-between-sathish-and-bac-clunky).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below method to add data to a combobox in gridview. If you dont have a list you can add items to the combobox as:

```
cmbdgv.Items.Add("Test");

private void bindDataToDataGridViewCombo() {
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmbdgv = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    List<String> itemCodeList = new List<String>();
    cmbdgv.DataSource = itemCodeList;
    cmbdgv.HeaderText = "Test";
    cmbdgv.Name = "Test";
    cmbdgv.Width = 270;
    cmbdgv.Columns.Add(dgvCmbForums);
    cmbdgv.Columns["Test"].DisplayIndex = 0;
}
```

After adding if you want to capture the combobox selection change you can use below event in the datagridview.

```
ComboBox cbm;
DataGridViewCell currentCell;

private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control is ComboBox)
    {
        cbm = (ComboBox)e.Control;

        if (cbm != null)
        {
            cbm.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(cbm_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }

        currentCell = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell;
    }
}

void cbm_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(EndEdit));
}


void EndEdit()
{
    if (cbm != null)
    {
        string SelectedItem=cbm.SelectedItem.ToString();
        int i = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Test"].Value = SelectedItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it neccesary to add `if (cbm != null)` condition?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to set the value to a Combobox in a DataGridView, see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537262/programmatically-set-selected-index-of-a-combobox-in-datagridview/24537502#24537502) answer will help.

To get the selected item of the Combobox (example):

```
comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox_ComboSelectionChanged);

private void comboBox_ComboSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
            if (myDGV.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5)
            {
                int selectedIndex;
                string selectedItem;

                selectedIndex = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedIndex;  // handle an error here.
                // get the selected item from the combobox
                var combo = sender as ComboBox;

                if (selectedIndex == -1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No value has been selected");
                }
                else
                {
                    // note that SelectedItem may be null
                    selectedItem = combo.SelectedItem.ToString();

                    if (selectedItem != null)
                    {
                        // Your code
```

Comment: I meant, there is a comboBox in every row of a DataGridView