# this code can load a DataGridView column but can not select a value from this column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

```
Dim Raw As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
Raw.HeaderText = "Raw Material"
Raw.Name = "cmb"
con.Open()
cmd = New SqlCommand("select Raw from Raws ", con)
DR = cmd.ExecuteReader
While DR.Read()
    Raw.Items.AddRange(DR("Raw").ToString())
End While
DR.Close()
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(Raw)
con.Close()
```

I want to know how to select a value from the datagridview column by using code.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do please? Also, is there anything you have tried to achieve what you seek?

Comment: this code loads a list of items in the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn but if you want to select on of the items you have to select it manually and i want a code that can make me select for example the 2nd item in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically set selected index of a ComboBox in DataGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537262/programmatically-set-selected-index-of-a-combobox-in-datagridview)